# scalling image with getScaledInstance() in java

Tags: java, image, get

Can anyone explain this, there are 3 ways by which I have created Image object but only the last object(k) can be successfully scaled using getscalledinstance().

```
public class scalingTest extends JPanel {

    public static Image i;
    public static Image j;
    public static Image k;
    scalingTest() throws IOException
    {
        i = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:/Users/Prashant/Desktop/2.png");
        j = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Prashant/Desktop/2.png").getImage();
        k = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Prashant/Desktop/2.png"));
    }
    public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Scaling TEST");
        jf.add(new scalingTest());
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(i.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(j.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), 100, 100, this);
        g.drawImage(k.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), 200, 200, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Javadoc of Image.getScaledInstance:

> A new `Image` object is returned which will render 
>        the image at the specified `width` and 
>        `height` by default.  The new `Image` object
>        may be loaded asynchronously even if the original source image
>        has already been loaded completely.

Ensure the scaled image is really *there* when you try to draw it (look for "ensure image is fully loaded" if you need advice how to do that). The reason it works with the image obtained through ImageIO is that ImageIO gives you a BufferedImage, and that is always loaded.

Also note: For the purpose of simply drawing an image to a size other than the images size, you do not need to create a scaled instance - Graphics has methods to draw images in a different size on the fly. You might be better off using that, depending on use case.